# Difficulty of the book Mathematical Logic by Mileti

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, book-recommendation

I am currently working through the book *Mathematical Logic* by Mileti ([online version](https://mileti.math.grinnell.edu/MathematicalLogic.pdf)) and just finished the second chapter (induction and recursion). I have to admit that it is quite challenging and whereas I think I can follow through, it really takes a lot of effort and time to thoroughly understand the ideas since they are so abstract for me. Has anyone worked through it and could let me know if the density and difficulty will continue in that rate or if one quickly gets used to it?

Thanks

Comment: What book, please?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The entire question should be in the body, not just in the title

Comment: I'm not familiar with the textbook, but recursion is a standard tool used to define mathematically the syntax of a formal language. You can browse it and skip it at first, trying to familiarize with the following treatment of propositional logic. Then, reread it, if necessary.

Comment: What is your motivation for studying mathematical logic? If it is to learn the basic methods of mathematical proof, you may want to consider a different starting point.

Comment: Book name is in the body now- sorry. I actually went through Linear Algebra I & II as well as through a bit of real analysis before, so many concepts somehow ring a bell (on a more abstract level though). The reason why I am reading that book is because I want to see a proof of Gödels incompleteness theorem! It's not that I am totally in the dark with Mileti's book, but that I would like to know what I should prepare for in the course of the book in terms of work load and difficulty development of concepts and proofs.

Comment: Mileti is above the level I'd generically expect someone new to logic to be able to go through on their own (with an instructor is a different question). It's possible to start with Mileti sure, but I'd recommend picking up a book on proofs first, or a more intro text on logic, or both. Skimming through Mileti now, it appears many of the constructions are quite technical, and aren't the sort of things I consider to 1) be easily understood by someone new to the area, 2) be widely applicable outside the book's own content. It's good stuff to know, just not a great starting point imo.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, I now do have a good idea of what I can expect going forward with this book (and some backup plans should I get too frustrated with it at some point). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, a friend of mine reviewed this book, and he asked for my feedback on the review, so I spent quite some time looking at it from a pedagogical viewpoint. (I don't think his review has appeared yet, or I'd link to it.)

It's one of the more difficult intro texts on the subject (though it has its strengths). Enderton’s *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* or Leary’s *A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic* would be easier going, I think.

We both questioned the value of the second chapter. Mileti provides a very abstract general framework for definitions by induction. Other books cover this material more concretely and intuitively. Typically you'll see "well-formed formula" of the sentential calculus defined via a few clauses, with maybe a page or two of discussion. Analogous definitions for the predicate calculus, free and bound variables, etc., appear later without much fuss and bother. The reader quickly gets used to the technique.

Mileti's approach allows him to quote general results for these specific cases. It provides a greater degree of rigor, and much later in the book it offers other dividends, but (IMO) his Chapter 2 should have been an appendix, or omitted altogether.

After this inauspicious start, the going does get smoother, but it remains less "user friendly" than most other intros. I particularly liked the wealth of applications to other branches of mathematics, more than you'll usually find in these books. On the other hand, if you don't have the necessary background in those fields (mostly algebra), this will not be a plus.

Comment: Yes, the inductions he introduced somehow seemed to be the "mother" of all inductions :D

I also realized that theoretically, one only needs a very basic introduction to some analysis and linear algebra to get started with the book. However, truly following all the content and thoughts requires a solid level of mathematical education  (at least for me who is far from a a math genius).

Had you said it will get much more difficult and abstract, I think I would have left the book. As long as the "difficulty" doesn't increase significantly anymore, I think I will continue.

Thanks Mr Weiss!

Comment: I would recommend trying another book, either before or in parallel with Mileti. Mileti would make a very good follow up to an easier book like Enderton.

Comment: Also, if your main interest is Gödel’s incompleteness theorems, you might want to try one of several shorter treatments focusing on that. You also can skip many of the intermediate chapters in Mileti.

Comment: Ok understood, I will then look into Enderton for now.

Comment: Another book I warmly recommend, for Gödel's theorems and much else, is Stillwell's *Roads to Infinity*.